# Firewall pop-up notifications won't go away (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, firewall

So, recently I got a new laptop (It's an HP, with windows 10)
There's a pop up notification from windows firewall that shows up almost every other minute

[image: Here it is]

I've hit accept and simply closed it multiple times, but it won't go away

I've also gone in settings and disabled notifications for the firewall multiple times, but it keeps resetting. it only takes a minute or two for it to reset so the pop-up notification starts up pretty soon
I've restarted my computer as well, nothing

Any advice? anything is appreciated,
Thanks!

(Its popped up like at least 10 times while I wrote this, I hope that gets the point across that this is pretty inconvinient, and I'd like to fix it soon)

Comment: Try enabling "Private network" and see what happens.

Comment: Does it always pop up for this specific program or is it for all kinds of different programs?

Comment: It seems it went away for longer, but it's still popping up, heh @DavidPostill

Comment: @cascer1 always that program, it's a pre-installed program too

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT entered the command. an error message came up: IMPORTANT "netsh firewall" is deprecated;                                                  use "netsh advfirewall firewall" comands                                                                instead of "netsh firewall", see KB article 947709 at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=121488                                                     I've checked out the site but I'm not great with commands so I thought I'd send it to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a Windows Firewall rule with **NETSH** to allow this application outbound on any profile with an elevated command prompt run as administrator with the below syntax or something similar:

**Allow App Outbound**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="HP Network Communicator" dir=out action=allow program="C:\Program Files\hp\hp envy 4500 series\bin\hpnetworkscommunicator.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

If you need to setup an inbound rule in the Windows Firewall to allow this app outbound without the prompt each time, then you can run the below with an elevated command prompt run as administrator:

**Allow App Inbound**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="HP Network Communicator" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files\hp\hp envy 4500 series\bin\hpnetworkscommunicator.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**NETSH**](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)
- [**Top 10: Windows Firewall Netsh Commands**](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/top-10-windows-firewall-netsh-commands)